# How to adjust the default starting position of main text in a frame, for a template using beamer class

Tags: beamer, positioning

I am making a latex template for presentation slides using `beamer` class, based on a template made in microsoft powerpoint.

[image]

The codes are as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
This line should be 2.5 cm away from the left ledge of the slide.
\begin{itemize}
\item the item symbol {\color{blue}\small $\blacktriangleright$} should also be 2.5 cm away from the left edge of the slide.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I want to also set the normal text and the bullet symbol from `itemiz` both `2.5 cm` away from the left edge of the slide. I want to make this style as in the template (`beamerinnerthememycompany.sty`), meaning for every `\begin{frame} and \end{frame}` in the main `.tex` file, this should be automatically done.

Can anyone show me how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). This is not what is obtained with the default setup of beamer.

Comment: Have a look at the beamer user guide: "Frame and Margin Sizes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the frametitle, as it would be a waste of time to redefine it without knowing your modified definition.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=2.5cm}
\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
This line should be 2.5 cm away from the left ledge of the slide.
\begin{itemize}
\item the item symbol {\color{blue}\small $\blacktriangleright$} should also be 2.5 cm away from the left edge of the slide.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]